# Active connections exceed maximum set with sp_configure 'user connections'

Tags: sql-server

I tried limiting the number of active connections to my server with:

```
-- Limit the max number of active connections to 100
EXEC sp_configure 'user connections', 20;
RECONFIGURE;
```

However, after restarting the server, when I check the number of connections:

```
-- View total number of active connections
SELECT 
    COUNT(dbid) as TotalConnections
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
```

I get a number of connections above the limit I just set, for example 25 in this case.

Comment: You counted not only user connections

Comment: select count(*)
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where is_user_process = 1

Comment: Got it. I was also counting the system process connections, such as the ones under the 'sa' login.